# Select a particular UIView when view is loaded in one xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

I have 5 segmented contol segments on navigation bar and the requirement of my app is such that I have to change views in within one segment only. Now I have two `UIViews` within one xib. I have set an integer flag and depending on that flag, I need to change the views. I am posting this because both the view will have a table view within one xib and they will have different number of rows, different `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. So two questions are - How to select a particular view depending on the flag and How to manage delegate methods of both UIViews as file owner will create issues? If someone suggest to create a separate class with UIViewController, then how to overwrite / replace the view for that particular segment?

Please note that i am not using storyboards. App is based on XIB's only

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question (english not native for me), one of the ways to obtain the necessary data:

1. you can use `NSArray *subviews = [[self view] subviews];` for get collection of all views (collection can include not only `UIView` objects) in your view controller assigned to XIB;
2. you can check each object belonging to the class `[object isKindOfClass:[UIView class]];` to find needed `UIViews`;
3. you can determine `UIView`s by property `tag` (can set in XIB); or use some other properties for it.
4. in found `UIView` you can again get all subviews `[view subviews];` and use `[object isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]];` to find needed table;
5. you can use reference to found `UITableView` in delegate methods to determine to which table the delegate method is called. For example: in
   `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method you need check `tableView`